# How to extend a Fantom class that implements a serialisation constructor?

Tags: fantom

A powerful feature of Fantom programming language is the [it-block constructor](http://fantom.org/doc/docLang/Serialization), often used in serializable classes. Unfortunately I cannot find documentation detailed enough to do what I though should be pretty simple: Extending a class that declares this type of constructor. The best documentation I've found so far is in [this post](http://fantom.org/forum/topic/2259), but doesn't show an example of what I'm trying to do.

Let's say I have these classes:

```
class Animal {
  protected const Str name
  new make( |This| f ) { f(this) }
  override Str toStr() { "I'm an Animal and my name is $name" }
}

class Main {
  Void main() {
    a := Animal {
      name = "Flipper"
    }
    echo( a )
  }
}
```

So far so good, it prints: "I'm an Animal and my name is Flipper". Now I want to extend Animal with this class:

```
class Dog : Animal {
  override Str toStr() { "I'm an Dog and my name is $name" }
}
```

But Fantom compiler says:

```
Must call super class constructor in 'make'
```

So I changed the class to be:

```
class Dog : Animal {
  new make( |This| f ) : super( this ) { f(this) }
  override Str toStr() { "I'm an Dog and my name is $name" }
}
```

But now the compiler complains:

```
invalid args make(|Playground::Animal->sys::Void|), not (Playground::Dog)
```

which makes sense since I'm passing a Dog instance, instead of an Animal, so what should I be passing to the super constructor then?

Answer (score 1):

After giving a bit more thought to the compiler error I realised all what I had to pass was f:

```
class Dog : Animal {
  new make( |This| f ) : super( f ) { }
  override Str toStr() { "I'm an Dog and my name is $name" }
}
```

I hope this helps others.

Comment: There is no need to call `f(this)` in Dog's ctor because it has already been called in Animal's ctor.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Steve. I removed the unneeded invocation.